# New for ISO 8583: Getting invalid bitmap for my ISO message in JMeter for POS Purchase transaction

Tags: jmeter, iso8583, jpos

I am new to ISO 8583 message.
I am getting Invalid bitmap error in LB balancer logs where I am sending the request from JMETER.

```
    2.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]D-BLR-10013: Read 12 bytes
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]CCTClient::check_after() - actived
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]CCTClient::check() ret:None
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]L-BLR-10017: Recv 12 bytes from 
     _F_JS[265], ID[269616260] at 1642013059 462
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]D-ISOHDL-0001: Process field: h1
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]D-ISOHDL-0001: Process field: mti
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]E-ISOHDL-2005: Exceed end of msg, field[mti]
     22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]E-ISOHDL-0004: Error in parsing iso8583 msg, no 
 msgid generated
    22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]E-BLR-70003: Retrieve MsgInfo failed, src port: 
    _F_JS.
    22.01.12 21:44:19.462 [     blr:16449792]D-BLR-70024: Handler resp method return -1
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]D-BLR-10013: Read 15 bytes
     22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]L-BLR-10017: Recv 15 bytes from 
    [265], ID[2797415146] at 1642013060 589
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]D-ISOHDL-0001: Process field: h1
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]D-ISOHDL-0001: Process field: mti
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]D-ISOHDL-0001: Process field: 0
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]E-ISOHDL-1000: Invalid bitmap field, at msg offset[e]
    22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]E-ISOHDL-0004: Error in parsing iso8583 msg, no msgid 
      generated
      22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]E-BLR-70003: Retrieve MsgInfo failed, src port: 
      _F_JS.
      22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]D-BLR-70024: Handler resp method return -1
     22.01.12 21:44:20.589 [     blr:16449792]CCTClient::check() ret:None'
```

I am seeing in JMeter debug log.

This is the packed request it is forming.

```
'313230304632333030374331323843323841303531363434303634373030313430323135373730303030303030303030303030303032303030313132323134323031303031343432323230313132303934323031373130333031373033333443303130303332303030343139393030333734323036353838383437303233373334383433353137383234393633363636363636363636363636363638353237343139363633333120202030303652414a425031303336383234374646463031303030303430303030303033373137305f2a020682820219808407a0000002281010950500000080019a032112149c01009f02060000000050009f03060000000000009f10120110a040002a00000000000000000000ffff9ff1a0206829f2608cfef18b5eaecb9949f2701809f3303e008089f34031f03029f3501229f3602003b9f3704055b6e3b50046d6164619f6e07068200003030009f120a6d6164612044656269744f07af00000022810109f1e08353030313030343830303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303131303232303330303431303530343030353030374e30303030303045303030303030303039303130303030303030303030313130303030303030303031323130333431383030303133313033343139303030313431333438313033343030313531353036303030393136303130313031303232423439313137424646464646464646'
```

JMeter request message:

```xml
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">
       <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[C:/MTesting/POC/] -->
      <header>6000376D25</header>
      <field id="0" value="1200"/>
      <field id="1" value="F23007C128C28A05"/>
      <field id="2" value="4406470014021577"/>
      <field id="3" value="000000"/>
      <field id="4" value="000000000200"/>
      <field id="7" value="0112212717"/>
      <field id="11" value="1442"/>
      <field id="12" value="220112092717"/>
      <field id="22" value="71030170334C"/>
      <field id="23" value="0"/>
      <field id="24" value="200"/>
      <field id="25" value="1990"/>
      <field id="26" value="742"/>
      <field id="32" value="588847"/>
      <field id="35" value="37"/>
      <field id="37" value="147987678722"/>
      <field id="41" value="6366666666666666"/>
      <field id="42" value="852741966331"/>
      <field id="47" value="BANBP1"/>
      <field id="49" value="682"/>
      <field id="53" value="47FFF010000400000037" type="binary"/>
      <field id="55"  
      <field id="62" 
      <field id="64" value="2B49117BFFFFFFFF" type="binary"/>
      </isomsg>
```

Hex dump generated from request

```
    <!--
0000  31 32 30 30 46 32 33 30  30 37 43 31 32 38 43 32  1200F23007C128C2
0010  38 41 30 35 31 36 34 34  30 36 34 37 30 30 31 34  8A05164406470014
0020  30 32 31 35 37 37 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0215770000000000
0030  30 30 30 30 30 32 30 30  30 31 31 32 32 31 32 37  0000020001122127
0040  31 37 30 30 31 34 34 32  32 32 30 31 31 32 30 39  1700144222011209
0050  32 37 31 37 37 31 30 33  30 31 37 30 33 33 34 43  271771030170334C
0060  30 31 30 30 33 32 30 30  30 34 31 39 39 30 30 33  0100320004199003
0070  37 34 32 30 36 35 38 38  38 34 37 30 32 33 37 31  7420658884702371
0080  34 37 39 38 37 36 37 38  37 32 32 36 33 36 36 36  4798767872263666
0090  36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36  36 36 36 38 35 32 37 34  6666666666685274
00a0  31 39 36 36 33 33 31 20  20 20 30 30 36 52 41 4A  1966331   006RAJ
00b0  42 50 31 30 33 36 38 32  34 37 46 46 46 30 31 30  BP10368247FFF010
00c0  30 30 30 34 30 30 30 30  30 30 33 37 31 37 30 5F  000400000037170_
00d0  2A 02 06 82 82 02 19 80  84 07 A0 00 00 02 28 10  *.............(.
00e0  10 95 05 00 00 00 80 01  9A 03 21 12 14 9C 01 00  ..........!.....
00f0  9F 02 06 00 00 00 00 50  00 9F 03 06 00 00 00 00  .......P........
0100  00 00 9F 10 12 01 10 A0  40 00 2A 00 00 00 00 00  ........@.*.....
0110  00 00 00 00 00 FF FF 9F  F1 A0 20 68 29 F2 60 8C  .......... h).`.
0120  FE F1 8B 5E AE CB 99 49  F2 70 18 09 F3 30 3E 00  ...^...I.p...0>.
0130  80 89 F3 40 31 F0 30 29  F3 50 12 29 F3 60 20 03  ...@1.0).P.).` .
0140  B9 F3 70 40 55 B6 E3 B5  00 46 D6 16 46 19 F6 E0  ..p@U....F..F...
0150  70 68 20 00 03 03 00 09  F1 20 A6 D6 16 46 12 04  ph ...... ...F..
0160  46 56 26 97 44 F0 7A F0  00 00 02 28 10 10 9F 1E  FV&.D.z....(....
0170  08 35 30 30 31 30 30 34  38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  .500100480000000
0180  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0190  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01b0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01c0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01d0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01e0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
01f0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0200  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0210  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0220  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0230  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0240  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0250  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0260  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0270  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0280  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0290  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02b0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02c0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02d0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02e0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
02f0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0300  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0310  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0320  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0330  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0340  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0350  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0360  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0370  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0380  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0390  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03b0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03c0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03d0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03e0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
03f0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0400  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0410  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0420  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0430  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0440  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0450  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0460  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0470  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0480  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
0490  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
04a0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
04b0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
04c0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
04d0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0000000000000000
04e0  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 31 31 30  0000000000000110
04f0  32 32 30 33 30 30 34 31  30 35 30 34 30 30 35 30  2203004105040050
0500  30 37 4E 30 30 30 30 30  30 45 30 30 30 30 30 30  07N000000E000000
0510  30 30 39 30 31 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31  0090100000000001
0520  31 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 31 32 31 30 33 34  1000000000121034
0530  31 38 30 30 30 31 33 31  30 33 34 31 39 30 30 30  1800013103419000
0540  31 34 31 33 34 38 31 30  33 34 30 30 31 35 31 35  1413481034001515
0550  30 36 30 30 30 39 31 36  30 31 30 31 30 31 30 32  0600091601010102
0560  32 42 34 39 31 31 37 42  46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46  2B49117BFFFFFFFF
-->
```

Can any one guide us where is the issue with my request.
Header we are passing is like this - 6000376D25
Is passing message length is mandatory?
How to pass the message length in the beginning of the hex dump if it is mandatory?

Comment: JMeter (via jPOS) automatically adds the needed lengths provided you select the appropriate channel, we can't tell you which is the correct channel and packager because we don't know a thing about the interface you are trying to connect to. You need to carefully read the specs and select the appropriate channel and packager configuration

Comment: I am using JMeter tool as POS and hitting the request to Load Balancer, using IP and one port where LB is listening for an incoming requests.
Even I am using HEX Channel while sending the request.
Please let me know if you can guide me.

Comment: The only people who can help you are the responsible of the system you are trying to connect to, at least I cannot guess the format they are expecting, therefore I cannot guide you on how to configure JMeter to send the data in the format that system is excepcting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending something very weird.

- Your XML file to use with the GenericPackager is malformed, see the [JavaDoc](http://jpos.org/doc/javadoc/org/jpos/iso/packager/GenericPackager.html) for the correct format
- Your message starts with `3132` which is kind of [reserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583#Message_type_indicator_(MTI)) therefore cannot be used

So either the plugin you're using is not compatible with your requirements or you're using wrong configuration. Unfortunately we cannot help further without knowing the setup details on the other end, if there is a Java developer with POS knowledge you could ask him or her to take a look and see what's wrong on both ends, it might be the case you will need to create the code for sending POS messages in [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [write your own plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-develop-a-jmeter-plugin-intro-and-best-practices) if the current implementation cannot be used for some reason.

Comment: Dmitri, actually it seems that in the application server logs message starts from the hex value of header and then MTI, bitmap and other data elements as TPDU(Header) in JMeter is handled by its own way. At least we are able to send the request to reach to the backend application server. Earlier it was rejected from the first interface like LB itself. Actually, our data element 3 is getting the value of data element 4 at backend server and data element 4 is taking the value of next data element after 4 which is data element 7. Its seems the application expects more initial bytes before ISO msg

Comment: Still I am getting bitmap errors. Actually I am passing bitmap as 723007C128C28A05 but its converting to F23007C128C28A05 in hex dump generation.

As I experimented till now I am seeing that only through NAC Channel our request is able to reach till the backend server.
Could you please guide us that where exactly In JMeter we can set the whole ISO message length if it can be handled by JMeter? Otherwise, how we will send the 2 byte message length before the ISO message if there is no place holder in JMeter.

Comment: Is there different testpackager.xml for NAC Channel?